# Python Basics - Dictionary comprehension -- turn all values into lists - without nesting existing [[value lists]]

Tags: python, dictionary

if we had

```
dictionary = {'a': 'one', 
            'b': 'two', 
            'c': ['three', 'four']
            }
```

Is there a way to improve the following comprehension to not nest value of 'c' ?
`{key: [value] for key, value in dict.items()}`

eg

```
>>>dictionary = {'a': 'one', 
            'b': 'two', 
            'c': ['three', 'four']
            }
>>>dictionary = {key: [value] for key, value in dictionary.items()}
>>>print(dictionary)

{'a': ['one'], 'b': ['two'], 'c': [['three', 'four']]}
```

Can it be sovlved using conditions in the comprehension?

If not, what could be a neat solution to not double list any values?
With or w/o modules is fine

Seen some pretty ugly solutions instead of dict comprehensions, for similar but more complicated operations. Really hoping there's a nice way to not mess up the values.
Thank you

- edit to add context.

  ```
   favourite_languages = {
       'jen': 'python',
       'sarah': 'c',
       'edward': 'ruby',
       'phil': ['python', 'haskell'],
       }

   for name, languages in favourite_languages.items():
       print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite languages are:")
       for language in languages:
           print(f"\t{language.title()}")
  ```

I think the values(strings) need to all be put/turned into lists, otherwise the output messes up, because of the

```
    for language in languages:
```

Output Is:

```
    Jen's favourite languages are:
        P
        Y
        T
        H
        O
        N
```

I tried to reassign the dictionary to a comprehension, but it obviously works on everything as is.. so everything goes into a list.

```
    favourite_languages = {name: [languages] for name, languages 
    in favourite_languages.items()}
```

The final key-value pair messes up, gets double listed

```
    print(favourite_languages)
    {'jen': ['python'], 'sarah': ['c'], 'edward': ['ruby'], 
    'phil': [['python', 'haskell']]}
```

Comment: The best would probably be to have coherent input data instead of this mix of strings and lists...

Comment: @roganjosh thank you! Looks great, though I'm not familar with this [*value}
Could you explain the logic, or direct me to the terminology?

[*value] -- Is there a name for what this is doing/ name for the use of *  ?

Is it saying "don't perform this operation" ?

Comment: @DangerNoodle That's the unpacking operator.

Comment: That or the "splat operator"

Answer (score 0):

You can kinda solve it using conditionals

```
data = {'a': 'one',
    'b': 'two',
    'c': ['three', 'four']
}
dictionary = {key: [value] for key, value in data.items() if not isinstance(value, list)}
dictionary1 = {key: value for key, value in data.items() if isinstance(value, list)}
dictionary.update(dictionary1)
```

The problem is this will iterate twice over data.items().

You can use generator expressions to achieve this too

```
data = {'a': 'one',
    'b': 'two',
    'c': ['three', 'four']
}
dictionary = dict((key,value) if isinstance(value,list) else (key,[value]) for key, value in data.items())
```

Also you can check the object's type before printing it and branching the logic as needed

```
favourite_languages = {
    'jen': 'python',
    'sarah': 'c',
    'edward': 'ruby',
    'phil': ['python', 'haskell'],
}
for name, languages in favourite_languages.items():
    print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite languages are:")
    if not isinstance(languages, list):
        for language in languages:
            print(f"\t{language.title()}")
    else:
        print(f"\t{languages.title()}")
```